# Braintree Webhook for Payment failure to Submerchant

Tags: php, webhooks, braintree, braintree-sandbox

As per documentation what I had understood is, when we release funds from escrow, if there is any issue with sub-merchant if we setup a webhook for `Disbursement Exception` then it will be notified to us. Braintree will hit the endpoint url which we have configured in control panel with request parameters, I want to find for which transactions & sub-merchant issue is raised. From [this](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/webhooks/disbursement/php#disbursement) doc its clear that transactions ids they will send in request parameters but its not clearly given about sub-merchant details anywhere in the doc.

I tried even [sample payload](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/webhooks/testing-go-live/php), payload doesn't reflect actual request parameters. To know myself what parameters will be sent by Braintree when `Disbursement Exception` occurs I created a sub-merchant in sandbox using `PHP SDK` with   `destination` as `Braintree_Test_MerchantAccount::$bankRejectedUpdateFundingInformation`, after that I created few sale transactions where funds has to release from escrow to newly create sub-merchant. From two days I'm waiting for that Braintree will hit endpoint url which I configured in control panel when it tries to release funds to sub-merchant but Braintee never hit endpoint url and still escrow status is `Release Pending`.

My question in-short: How to know for which sub-merchant disbursement exception is occurred when braintree webhook hit the endpoint url ?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).</sub>

In the case of a disbursement exception, the resulting webhook payload will still contain a `disbursement` object. **The disbursement object will have a `merchantAccount` parameter, which contains info about the submerchant account for which disbursement failed, including `id`, the submerchant's merchant account ID.** [Here's the relevant page in the Braintree dev docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/webhooks/disbursement/php#disbursement.merchant_account).

In code, here's what that looks like: once you've [parsed the webhook notification](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/webhooks/parse) and confirmed that `$webhookNotification->kind` is `Braintree_WebhookNotification::DISBURSEMENT_EXCEPTION`, then you can use

**`$webhookNotification->disbursement->merchantAccount->id`**

to get the ID. On the disbursement object, you also can get the reason for the failure with `exceptionMessage`, the list of transactions in the failed disbursement with `transactionIds`, and a suggested next step with `followUpAction`.

If you're using the latest version of the Braintree PHP SDK (currently 3.22.0), then on a sample notification, `$webhookNotification->disbursement->merchantAccount->id` will be set to "merchant_account_token".